# Differences between contracts and facades laravel

Tags: oop, interface, laravel-5.1

I have been doing laravel since 4 months. I don't find a clear difference between facades and contracts as they both are set of interfaces. Why would i use facades instead of contracts or contracts instead of facades?

Answer (score 13):

The question whether to use `Facade` or `Contract` boils down how you want to resolve your classes and if you want to use interfaces.

**Facade**

- A facade is a class and not an interface ([here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/App.php) is an example facade).
- A facade is **only** used to load a class from service container more convenient
- The class that is going to be loaded is determent in the `getFacadeAccessor()` method of the facade class.

Example:

```
// Without facade - resolving from service container
app('some_service')->methodName();

// Do the same through facade:
someService::methodName();
```

**Contract**

- A contract is an interface ([here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Config/Repository.php) is an example)
- A contract is used to load a class from service container more convenient **AND** as an interface
- The class that is going to be loaded is determined in the service container, see [Binding Interfaces To Implementations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations)

Example: Assuming that class `some_service` implements interface `Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository`:

```
// resolving class directly from service container
app('some_service')->methodName();

// resolve through binding from contract
app('Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository')->methodName();
```